# Stuck on trying to turn input into a string of certain format

Tags: php

So I have a field in the db for delivery times, and it is of certain format (not my design for sure!):
Here are a couple of examples:

M, T, W, TH ; MTWTH 9 TO 4 CLOSED 12 TO 1

T, W, TH, F ; TTHF 9 TO 5 CLOSED 12 TO 2, W 9 TO 12

T, W, TH, F ; T 10 TO 7 CLOSED 2 TO 3, WTH 9 TO 6 CLOSED 1 TO 2, F 8 TO 5 CLOSED 1 TO 2

So basically, you have a list of days, separated by a comma, followed by semi-colon.
After semi-colon there is a list of days, not separated, and followed by delivery times including break times.
The problem is, delivery times can be different for each day, same for all days, or same for let's say Monday and tuesday, then different for Wednesday, and same for Thursday and Friday (but Thursday and Friday have different delivery times then Monday and Tuesday).
And if delivery times match for some days, those days should be grouped together, with delivery times listed after the group days, then other matched or single days listed after that. First day for which there are delivery hours specified must go first.

I know, the format is ridiculous and delivery days/times should be in a separate table linked by organization id, but it's the format they use now for some download files.
I hope to change it later, but for now...
I can't figure out how to transform input from 4 drop-downs (From, To, Closed From, Closed To) into that format.
Any of the days may not have closing times at all. At least one day must have delivery times specified (I check for that).

I of course got the first part (before semi-colon) - that's easy, after that I'm totally stuck.
If all days for which there's delivery had the same hours, I wouldn't have issues. But since it can be totally different from day to day, I don't know how to do it.

So this is the processing block so far:

$trimmed is the array of POST values that has been trimmed,

$trimmed['1Monday'] is Monday From, $trimmed['2Monday'] is Monday To,

$trimmed['3Monday'] is Monday Closed From, $trimmed['4Monday'] is Monday Closed To.

So  $M_times variable will have open/closing times for Monday.

$days_del array is used to later create a string that is the first part of required format.

I can get the first day with some times specified and I can try to catch any matches after that, but that isn't useful if first delivery day has different values from the rest, yet there are some matching values after that. I'm not even sure that I need to use anoither (numbered) days array or I can do it with just the main one with M-F for keys.

```
<?php

$days = array('M' => 'Monday', 'T' => 'Tuesday', 'W' => 'Wednesday', 'TH' => 'Thursday', 'F' => 'Friday');

$days_numbered = array(1 => 'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F');

$days_del = $matches = $full_list = array();

$days_delivery2 = '';

$count_no_del = 0;  # initialize count for days with no delivery
$times_6 = '';



foreach ($days as $k => $v){  #####  Beginning of days loop


if (isset($trimmed["1$v"]) &&  isset($trimmed["2$v"])){ #  If both closing and opening times have been specified

$days_del[] = $k;
${$k.'_times'} = $trimmed["1$v"] . ' TO ' . $trimmed["2$v"];

if ((!isset($trimmed["3$v"]) && isset($trimmed["4$v"])) || (isset($trimmed["3$v"]) && !isset($trimmed["4$v"]))){  #  If only beginning or only end of lunch(?) break has been specified

$errors[] = 'Delivery times for $v - please specify both start and end of closing time.';

}elseif (isset($trimmed["3$v"]) && isset($trimmed["4$v"]){  #  If both beginning and end of lunch(?) breakh have been specified

${$k.'_times'} .= 'CLOSED' .  $trimmed["3$v"] . ' TO ' . $trimmed["4$v"];
}

    }elseif ((!isset($trimmed["1$v"]) &&  isset($trimmed["2$v"])) || (isset($trimmed["1$v"]) &&  !isset($trimmed["2$v"]))){  #  If only closing or only  opening time has been specified

$errors[] = 'Delivery times for $v - please specify both start and end of delivery time.';
${$k.'_times'} = NULL;

    }elseif (!isset($trimmed["1$v"]) &&  !isset($trimmed["2$v"])){  # No delivery times specified for this day

${$k.'_times'} = NULL;
$count_no_del++;

    }

$full_list["$k"] = ${$k.'_times'};

}  #####  End of days loop



if ($count_no_del > 0){  #  If there are no delivery days specified
$errors[] = 'You must specify delivery hours for at least one day of the week.';
}

$days_delivery1 = implode(',', $days_del);
$days_delivery1 = $days_delivery1 . ' ; ';



foreach ($days_numbered as $num => $val){  #  Getting first day for which delivery hours have been specified
if (isset(${$val.'_times'}) && (${$val.'_times'} != NULL)){
${'times_'.$num} = ${$val.'_times'};
$first_day = $num;
break;
}
}




$check_array = array_keys($full_list, ${'times_'.$first_day}));  #  checking how many other days match the delivery hours for the first specified day.

foreach ($check_array as $array_key){
$days_delivery2 .= $array_key;
}

$days_delivery2 .= " " . ${'times_'.$first_day};


$note_line = $days_delivery1 . " "  ; #  second part, something like 'MTH 9 To 5, TW 10 TO 5 CLOSED 1 TO 2, F 10 TO 2' should go a s the second part of the string.
?>
```

As you can see, after getting the first part of the string in that format ($days_delivery1) I'm stuck and don't know what the hell am I doing. I have a vouge idea of using 2 different arrays (main one and numbered one) and using array_keys to find matching values, but any time I try to work on it I just run into a wall. Any ideas would be much apreciated.

Comment: I see some `$v`s where there should be `$k`s - eg `if (isset($trimmed["1$v"])` should be `if (isset($trimmed["1$k"])`

Comment: Are all the time values integers? What about half hours or smaller increments? In fact it would make this a lit easier if you can show us the HTML form you use to collect the data.

Comment: No, $trimmed['1$v'] is correct - as the slect elements have names like '1Monday', etc. Yes, all time values are numbers, but I think they should be treated as strings, as there are no calculations being performed. They have half an hour values in current records, but for newly entered ones I want to cut that, it ridiculous enough format as is, I think having drop down 8-7 in hour increments will be enough.

Comment: But you said in you question `$trimmed['1M'] is Monday From`, *not* `$trimmed['1Monday'] is Monday From` - are you *sure* they should be `$v`s? Like I say, it would be a lot easier to give a full answer if you show us the HTML form where you collect the data.

Comment: The form is huge, That data is currently entered in a input field. And then someonw transforms that into the string of that format. They want to have 5 days lisetd with opening/closing times though, so there will be 4 drop-downs <select name='1Monday'> will be for Open From times and for options I run aloop so it's <option value='8'>8 AM</option>, <option value='9'>9 AM</option> etc...

Comment: So you are definitely sticking to your guns on the full day names and not the 1 or 2 letter codes for input names? It's doesn't make much of a difference to the answer I'm currently writing (it would be easy to change it either way) but I would like to be correct first time round...

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the question. Field naming is not the issue, it can be 1 M or 1 Monday or whatever... The issue is comparing values and organizing them for the second part of the string. I can change names to whatever (as long as they are coming from an array so it'll be easy to process for the whole week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that is potentially difficult here is grouping like entries for the second section. In order to overcome this, I suggest you convert the times to 4 digit representations to normalise them and concatenate the patterns, so create a "signature" for each pattern.

In the below example, I will be working on the principal that the following `$_POST` arrays will result in the corresponding result strings:

```
 $_POST1 = array(
   '1Monday' => 9,
   '2Monday' => 5,
   '3Monday' => 12,
   '4Monday' => 1,
   '1Tuesday' => 9,
   '2Tuesday' => 5,
   '3Tuesday' => 12,
   '4Tuesday' => 1,
   '1Wednesday' => 9,
   '2Wednesday' => 5,
   '3Wednesday' => 12,
   '4Wednesday' => 1,
   '1Thursday' => 9,
   '2Thursday' => 5,
   '3Thursday' => 12,
   '4Thursday' => 1,
   '1Friday' => 9,
   '2Friday' => 4,
   '3Friday' => 11,
   '4Friday' => 12
 );
 $result1 = "M, T, W, TH, F ; MTWTH 9 TO 5 CLOSED 12 TO 1, F 9 TO 4 CLOSED 11 TO 12";     

 $_POST2 = array(
   '1Monday' => '',
   '2Monday' => '',
   '3Monday' => '',
   '4Monday' => '',
   '1Tuesday' => 9,
   '2Tuesday' => 5,
   '3Tuesday' => 12,
   '4Tuesday' => 1,
   '1Wednesday' => 9,
   '2Wednesday' => 5,
   '3Wednesday' => 12,
   '4Wednesday' => 1,
   '1Thursday' => 9,
   '2Thursday' => 5,
   '3Thursday' => 12,
   '4Thursday' => 1,
   '1Friday' => 9,
   '2Friday' => 5,
   '3Friday' => 12,
   '4Friday' => 1
 );
 $result2 = "T, W, TH, F ; TWTHF 9 TO 5 CLOSED 12 TO 1";
```

Now let's take a look at how we'd process that data. I'm going to assume that we are working directly with the unprocessed POST array.

```
<?php

  // Obviously we will need this map if the inputs use the full day names
  $days = array('M' => 'Monday', 'T' => 'Tuesday', 'W' => 'Wednesday', 'TH' => 'Thursday', 'F' => 'Friday');

  // A couple of arrays to hold the results of the loop iterations
  $resultDays = $resultTimes = array();

  // First we iterate over the days
  foreach ($days as $dayCode => $dayFull) {

    // Data about this day
    $dayData = array(
      'open' => 0,
      'close' => 0,
      'lunchClose' => 0,
      'lunchOpen' => 0,
      'days' => array()
    );

    // First get the open/close times
    $open = $_POST["1$dayFull"];
    $close = $_POST["2$dayFull"];
    if (empty($open) || empty($close)) {
      // If we don't have both open/close times, skip this day
      continue;
    }

    // We definitely open on this day
    $resultDays[] = $dayCode;
    $dayData['open'] = $open;
    $dayData['close'] = $close;

    // Pad the strings to make the signature
    $openPadded = str_pad($open, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $closePadded = str_pad($close, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Now look at lunch times
    $lunchClose = $_POST["3$dayFull"];
    $lunchOpen = $_POST["4$dayFull"];
    if (!empty($lunchClose) || !empty($lunchOpen)) {
      // If we have both open/close times, add a lunch break

      // Add data to $dayData
      $dayData['lunchClose'] = $lunchClose;
      $dayData['lunchOpen'] = $lunchOpen;

      // Pad the strings to make the signature
      $lunchClosePadded = str_pad($lunchClose, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      $lunchOpenPadded = str_pad($lunchOpen, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    } else {
      // So we don't break this signature
      $lunchClosePadded = $lunchOpenPadded = '';
    }

    // Build the signature
    $signature = $openPadded.$closePadded.$lunchClosePadded.$lunchOpenPadded;

    // Add day data to result times array
    if (!isset($resultTimes[$signature])) {
      $resultTimes[$signature] = $dayData;
    }
    $resultTimes[$signature]['days'][] = $dayCode;

  }

  // Now we can build the string

  // Like you say, first part is easy
  $firstPart = implode(', ', $resultDays);

  // Loop $resultTimes and construct to more sensible arrangements
  $secondPart = array();
  foreach ($resultTimes as $block) {
    $str = implode('', $block['days'])." {$block['open']} TO {$block['close']}";
    if (!empty($block['lunchClose']) && !empty($block['lunchOpen'])) {
      $str .= " CLOSED {$block['lunchClose']} TO {$block['lunchOpen']}";
    }
    $secondPart[] = $str;
  }

  // Now we can construct the final string
  $finalResult = $firstPart." ; ".implode(', ', $secondPart);
```

[See](http://codepad.org/Z00P4H0N) it [working](http://codepad.org/qkxp6UB7).

Well, that was fun.

Comment: Cool, thanks A LOT! That's the logic I needed, tested with different scenarios, works correctly.